# Why I got this strange behavior for UIView with gradient background?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview

I am trying to add a gradient layer to a `UIView` (`ContentView`) that contains a `UILabel`.

My `UIView` implementation:

```
class ContentView: UIView {
    override init() {
        super.init()
        styleIt()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        styleIt()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        styleIt()
    }

    private func styleIt() {
        var gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.colors = [Utils.Colors.gray_ee.CGColor, Utils.Colors.gray_dd.CGColor]
        gradient.frame = bounds

        layer.insertSublayer(gradient, atIndex: 0)

        layer.borderColor = Utils.Colors.gray_aa.CGColor
        layer.borderWidth = 1

        layer.cornerRadius = 7.0
    }
}
```

But here is what I got as a result shown in the *iPhone 6 iOS Simulator*

[image]

Only the `UIView` with `cornerRadius` is having a strange behavior all other elements in this screenshot are not `UIView` elements.

I have tried to comment out border-related code and radius code, but still same issue.

**Edit: Here is another screenshot with green background for the container (`UIScrollView`) and all other blah blah labels are within a ContentView element to show the issue in a bigger context.**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
private var gradient: CAGradientLayer! // Make it a private variable

override init(frame: CGRect) { 
    // Only init(frame:) and init(coder:) are designated initializers. You don't need to override init(). Internally init() will call init(frame:)
    super.init(frame: frame)
    commonInit()
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    commonInit()
}

func commonInit() -> Void {
    // Create & add the layer
    gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    layer.addSublayer(gradient)

    // You need to set locations, startPoint, endPoint apart from colors
    // See Apple documentation for more info
    gradient.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
    gradient.startPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPointMake(0, 1)
    gradient.colors = [UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor, UIColor.greenColor().CGColor];
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    // bounds may not be correct in init(), better set the layer's frame here
    gradient.frame = bounds 
}
```

Comment: Almost there! but when I use `addSublayer(_:)` instead of `insertSublayer(_:, atIndex:)` the "inner" `UILabel` disappeared.

Comment: Then use `insertSublayer` -- `addSublayer` will place the layer above the existing UILabel. The other way is to make sure you add `UILabel` **after** adding the gradient layer.

Comment: I also had to set `cornerRadius` for the inserted gradient layer, too.

Comment: Or set `cornerRadius` on the view, and set its `clipToBounds` to true